# net/http hanging requests causing failure - RoR

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, net-http

I have a bit of code that checks the response code of a list of URL's and presents them back - I am having trouble with a few of URL's that are hanging which causes the application not load at all. How can I make the request to give up after 30 seconds and check the next URL marking the skipped URL as failure.

below is my current code;
(Model/status.rb)

```
 require "net/http"
 require "uri"

 class Status
def initialize(url)
    @url = url
end

def get_status
    response.code
end

def active?
    ["200","203","302"].include?(get_status) ? true : false
end

private

def lookup
    URI.parse(@url)
end
def http
    Net::HTTP.new(lookup.host, lookup.port)
end
def request
    Net::HTTP::Get.new(lookup.request_uri)
end
def response
    http.request(request)
end
end
```

(controllers/welcome_controller.rb)

```
class WelcomeController < ApplicationController
def index
@syndication = [
["http://v1.syndication.u01.example.uk/organisations?apikey=bbccdd", "U.INT 01"],
["http://v1.syndication.u02.example.uk/organisations?apikey=bbccdd", "U.INT 02"],


].collect { |url| logger.info("Boom #{url[0]}"); ["#{url[1]} (#{url[0]})", Status.new(url[0]).active?] }

 end

 end
```

Comment: Try to put `http.read_timeout = 30` in `response` method before request.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got the answer..

adding the following to my "def get_status"

```
def get_status 
    begin 
        response.code
    rescue Exception => e
        Rails.logger.info("Error #{e}")
    end
end
```

This logged the error and the went to the next URL